# Need to use the while loop to input Integer only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a simple programme to do the follow operation:

1. Define number of elements to be added to the list (.i.e. N=6)
2. Add the each element of the list by using input method [1,2,3,4,5,6]

But when i do the second step i have the following requirement.

I supposed to input integers always. If I add a string or other type of input, code should request to add Integer, until adding all the elements. End of the coded i suppose to add N number of Integers.

I have tried to do this with try/except as below code

```
def request_for_numbers():
    list2 = []
    number = int(input("Please input numbers need to be added to the list "))
    while True:
        if len(list2)<=number:
            element = input("Please input the element of the List : ")
            while True:
                try:
                    element=int(element)
                except:
                    print("Add Integer Value")
                    element=input()
            list2.append(element)
        
    print(len(list2))
```

When I tried this code, if i enter string value, i can see the output to request to enter the integer value. (So no problem here)
But if i add the integer, it is stopped with the first iteration. (.i.e. I can't add multiple integers to the list)

Comment: Try putting `break` immediately after `element = int(element)`, at the same level of indentation. This will pull you out of the `while True` loop. You might also want to combine the outer `while` loop with the `if` statement just inside of it - change it to `while len(list2) <= number:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def request_for_numbers():
    list2 = []
    while True:
        number = input("Please input numbers need to be added to the list ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
            break;
        except ValueError:
            pass
    
    
    while number!=0:
        element = input("Please input the element of the List : ")
        try:
            element=int(element)
            list2.append(element)
            number-=1
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter an Integer Value")
    
    print(len(list2))
request_for_numbers()
```

your while loop is not exiting

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write it as below

```
 def request_for_numbers():
    list2 = []
    number = int(input("Please input numbers need to be added to the list "))
    while True:
        if len(list2) > number:
            break
        element = input("Please input the element of the List : ")
        if (element.isdigit()):
            list2.append(element)
        else:
             print("Add Integer Value")
    
         
    
    print(len(list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the second `while True` in your code?
It creates an infinite loop of trying to parse element as Integer.

```
def request_for_numbers():
list2 = []
number = int(input("Please input numbers need to be added to the list "))
while True:
    if len(list2)<number:
        element = input("Please input the element of the List : ")
        #while True:
        try:
            element=int(element)
            list2.append(element)
        except ValueError:
            print("Add Integer Value")
            element=input()
    else:
        break
print(len(list2))
```

And try to use the exception you are expecting in `except` instead of catching all errors for it, at least when you know which error it will be.